# How to read anonymous type in a View MVC .Net Core

Tags: model-view-controller, .net-core

I am failing to read the anonymous type object that I pass in a view, but I can see values using Immediate Window ...but when i try to read the object I get an error.

See below Visual Studio screenshot

[image]

Please advise anyone ?

Answer (score -1):

> Passing anonymous types to view basically need casting to dynamic
>   types of Model when rendering at view level

**At Controller :**

```
return View(new { 
    Object1 = "Hey there", 
    Object2 = 154.32, 
    Object3 = new Emp(84, "Test") })
```

**At razor View just cast object accordingly ,as follows :**

```
@{
    string obj1 = (dynamic)Model.Object1;
    decimal obj2= (dynamic)Model.Object2;
    Emp obj3= (dynamic)Model.Object3;
}
```

Now got the required stuff at view from anonymous ,Play it around .